# Android RecyclerView LayoutManager Exception

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

Hi I'm having an issue with the new `Android Lollipop RecyclerView`

It *keeps crashing* with the following exception:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.onMeasure(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler, android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$State, int, int)' on a null object reference
```

Full stack trace can found here

The code used to initiate the `RecyclerView` is the same mostly the same as the tutorial, however for some reason this still complains. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The code can be accessed at: [gist here](https://gist.github.com/binpower93/48f25f2fd3fc9983dec3) and layout: [this gist](https://gist.github.com/binpower93/30447c6d09a49ae50144)

None of the `views`, or `objects` are `null`

Comment: When recyclerview is added to the view tree, it must have a layout manager before it is laid out. Given the error log, at the time measure call arrives, it does not have a layout manager yet.
Full stack trace should show where the problem is.

Comment: The stack trace Can be found here: http:/crashes.to/s/68cfe49fbd4. But as far as I can see there is absolutely no reference to my code in the stack trace.

Comment: Hmm this is interesting. I cannot see why the layout manager is missing. If you can send a sample app that reproduces the issue via public bug tracker or here, i'll be happy to look. Btw, should not be related to this crash but LinearLayoutManager does not support wrap content yet. Also you cannot set wrap content and also setHasFixedSize(true).

Comment: another thing, when you inflate the cardview, also pass the parent so that styles and other stuff are inherited properly.
 

    mCardView = (CardView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_lines_served, parent, false);

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add the following code:

```
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

**Before** adding adapter:

```
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 2):

In the android Api level 22 it will not give the error.
Instead it skips the layout if the Adapter is not found.

By showing the warning:

> RecyclerView﹕ No adapter attached; skipping layout

But your app will not crash and runs, but `recyclerView` doesn't shown.

Comment: I hate this change, always takes me 30 mins to find why the first RecyclerView in my new project is not showing @_@