# Android:my recycler view does not show list

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am a beginner in Android development and working on a small project to show the list of the existing sensors on the device. But I can get the list of sensor displayed. I debugged and I see that I get 18 sensors when I run the program but I can't show them on the Android screen.

listItem.java code :

```
    public class ListItem {
    private String title;

    public ListItem(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    private List<ListItem>  SensorItems;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.sensorsRV);
        SensorItems = new ArrayList<ListItem>();

        SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager) this.getSystemService(this.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        List sensorList = sensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL);

        for(int i = 0; i < sensorList.size(); i++){
            ListItem currentSensor = new ListItem(((Sensor)(sensorList.get(i))).getName());
            SensorItems.add(currentSensor);
        }
        adapter = new MyAdapter(SensorItems);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


}
```

MyAdapter.java

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    List <ListItem> listItems;
    private Context context;

    public MyAdapter(List<ListItem> listItems) {
        this.listItems = listItems;

    }

    //creates whenever our view holder is created
    @Override
    public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);

    }

    //this method is called after onCreateViewHolder to bind data to view holder to show actuall data to recycler view
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ListItem listItem = listItems.get(position);
        holder.headingTextView.setText(listItem.getTitle());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listItems.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public TextView headingTextView;
        Context context;
        public LinearLayout myLayout;


        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            myLayout = (LinearLayout) itemView;
            headingTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textVeiwHead);
            context = itemView.getContext();
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.sahar.devicesensors.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="30dp"
            android:text="List of Device's Sensors"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"/>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/sensorsRV"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="20dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textVeiwHead"
                        android:text="Heading"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

If some one can give me some hints why I can't get the list showing I really appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this on your MainActivity:

```
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
```

The Constructor of LayoutManager receives context. Context contains global information about application.

Activity extends from Context, so you can use activity for it.

Comment: Beat me to the punch ;)

Comment: @Tura, thank you. Tried your code, but It cause error saying Cannot resolve constructor LinearLayoutManager

Answer (score 1):

make some changes in main activty then after show data into recycler view.

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private RecyclerView recyclerView;
        private MyAdapter adapter;
        private List<ListItem> SensorItems;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.sensorsRV);

            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
            SensorItems = new ArrayList<ListItem>();

            SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager) this.getSystemService(this.SENSOR_SERVICE);
            List sensorList = sensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL);

            for (int i = 0; i < sensorList.size(); i++) {
                ListItem currentSensor = new ListItem(((Sensor) (sensorList.get(i))).getName());
                SensorItems.add(currentSensor);
            }
            adapter = new MyAdapter(SensorItems);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mContext);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

And continue setAdapter.

Comment: what would be the mContext here? I never defined it any where so far in my program. I replaced mContext with this and it crashed !!!!!

Comment: mContext = getApplicationContext();
This is your context.

Comment: Still crashing :(

Comment: Log of crash, please.

Comment: public MyAdapter(List<ListItem> listItems, Context context) {
        this.listItems = listItems;
this.context = context.
    }

you should delete line: context = itemView.getContext();

Comment: here is what I get. I cleaned the project, built it and still get this error.Instant Run performed a full build and install since
    the installation on the device does not match the local build on disk.

Answer (score 0):

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

You must `setLayoutManager` before `setAdapter`, because the adapter depends on the `LayoutManager`. And, you'd better use `wrap_content` for `layout_height` in your root node of `list_item.xml`.

Comment: The order of calling setXXX() does not matter. They don't affect exactly when they are assigned.

Comment: Some old support version of RecyclerView has this sequence issue, I've came across before. for safe I always put setAdaper to the last.   refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26446162/android-recyclerview-layoutmanager-exception

Answer (score 0):

I observe that you are not set layout manager in your recycler view.So you can set layout manager through xml like below :-

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager" >
```

Or you can also do above thing using code like below:-

```
//To show vertical scrolling list
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

//To show horizontal scrolling list
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
```